# How can non-superusers mount second internal HDD?

Tags: mount, permissions, hard-drive, mass-storage

Ubuntu/Linux newbie here.

Xubuntu 16.04.1 is installed on `/dev/sda` and old disk is now `/dev/sdb` and contains two partitions: the old Recovery Environment, as `/dev/sdb1`, in case things go wrong or I need to put original Dell system back, and the Windows-Ubuntu common play area, `/dev/sdb2` as NTFS, for general data, such as downloads, audio & video etc.

The primary user, which was created during Ubuntu installation, can `mount` and `unmount /dev/sdb2` freely. And it always mounts as `/media/username/Partition_Label/` . I then created a non-administrative second user on the same machine for my other household member and in theory she has rights to `un/mount` disks. So much so that the external exFAT HDD when plugged to the USB port can be mounted by that user via desktop action (double-clicking the disk icon for the partition). However, that second user cannot do the same to mount `/dev/sdb2`: it asks for the password of the primary user to mount it.

How can I solve this? Why can an USB-plugged external HDD be freely mounted by the non-admin user but the second internal HDD cannot?

If logs or screenshots are needed, please let me know of what.

Comment: If it's an internal drive, just add an entry for it in `/etc/fstab` so that it is mounted automatically at boot time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the drive at /etc/fstab file, you can use my recent answer to help yourself to do this:
[Mounting a device by fstab file](https://askubuntu.com/a/851482/621276)

Might it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Non-root users can use `udisksctl` command. Unlike `mount` command it doesn't require `sudo` privillege. It also checks if you have entry for the partition/drive in `/etc/fstab`, and if you do , it will mount to directory specified there.For instance,

```
$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb6                                                                                           
Mounted /dev/sdb6 at /mnt/HDD.
```