# How to sync dropbox with external hdd?

Tags: 16.04, dropbox

I can't move the Dropbox folder outside /home/$USER. How can I move it to an external HDD?

Comment: When you tried the Move, did you select Computer above your home folder name, then walk through `/media/username/something` folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dropbox preferences>account>location you can choose the directory where u will place the dropbox sync, but you first need to mount the directory at start.

The first thing u need to know is, if the partition where u want to place the dropbox sync is a Windows (8 or 10) partition, u need to disable fast boot in Windows:
[Disable fast start in Windows 10](http://acer--uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/37059/~/windows-10%3A-enable-or-disable-fast-startup)

Then you need to mount the device at start by using the /etc/fstab file:
See the devices connected to your computer:

```
sudo blkid
```

This will give you all the partitions avaible in your computer, you need to copy the label from the partition where you want to use dropbox.

Then create a directory for the partition in /media/{yourUser}:

```
sudo mkdir /media/{yourUser}/{partitionName}
```

Now you can mount at start the device by editing the /etc/fstab file:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

There you will paste at the end the label part you copied before, and you need to put like that:

```
#Data partition
UUID={UR BLKID LABEL NUMBERS} /media/{yourUser}/{partitionName} [ntfs|ext4] defaults 0 0
```

You will put ntfs, ext4 or another format in depends of the format u gave to your partition.

Hope it will help you, i have this working in my 16.04 by doing that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open dropbox preference. Go to Account tab.

[image]

2. Click on Move button under Location section. A file browser dialog box will appear and you will be able to select different location for your dropbox folder, even to to external hdd. Only you need to give correct path.

> To know the exact path of your external hdd open a folder in Nautilus, right click on it and check the Location of the folder in its Properties.

[image]

> **Note:** Your dropbox will not function properly if the external hdd is not mounted.